# Analyzing NDVI rasters with same dimensions but different extents with Raster Calculator

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, ndvi, analysis, plot

I have drone sourced remote sensing imagery (NDVI) of a trial site set up to measure yield response to varying nitrogen (N) rates.

The trial includes N rates ranging from 0 to 600 kg/ha. The trial features 40 plots with identical dimensions (2m x 10m). There are 4 repetitions of each N rate located randomly thoughout the trial site.

Can the NDVI imagery from each repetition (i.e. 4 individual plots) be analyzed using Raster Calculator in ArcGIS to determine the mean NDVI or can other software be used to perform this task? (Given that the spatial extent of each plot is effectively irrelevant for the required task)

Ultimately I'd like to output a single raster which displays an average for each repetition (4 separate NDVI images).

Comment: What GIS software? Try zonal statistics

Comment: Thanks. Zonal Statistics would definitely be good for generating some numbers. I guess I'd still like to output a single raster (showing slight variations between cells) to be able to present in reports rather than just an average value for the entire plot.